# Unable to read miFare NTAG216 after authentication using miFareSDK

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, ndef

I am using the MiFareSDK Lite given on the NXP site. I was about to do some basic stuff like reading the tag etc.

I was also able to password protect the tag with the following code.

```
byte[] passwd= new byte[] {(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x4f,(byte)0xd0,(byte)0x20};
byte[] packpwd= new byte[] {(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x4f}; 
inTag213215216.programPWDPack(passwd,packpwd);
inTag213215216.enablePasswordProtection(true,inTag213215216.getFirstUserpage());
```

After which in another session I call

```
inTag213215216.authenticatePwd(passwd,packpwd);
INdefMessage message =  inTag213215216.readNDEF();
```

But the read fails with exception, it was working previously without authentication. What should I do after authenticatePwd to read/write/resetpwd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was, when you authenticate and then try to read the NFC tag when doing a line by line debug(using android studio) the read fails, hence do NOT try this on debug mode with line by line debug.